# Select last row to meet condition

Tags: sql

I have a database and I want to output the VAL of a row that has a POSITION of 49 with the highest ID. I have this code but I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
SELECT ID, POSITION,
CASE WHEN POSITION = 49 THEN VAL END
FROM Log
```

Comment: first, start with the sql version

Comment: Please post sample data and expected output you want to see.

Answer (score 2):

simplest solution would be

`SQL-SERVER`

```
SELECT top 1 val
FROM Log
where position = 49
order by id desc
```

`MySQL`

```
   SELECT val
    FROM Log
    where position = 49
    order by id desc
    limit 1
```